# Cell Structure of $S^2 \times S^2$, and more generally applying theorem to product of CW-complexes

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, product-space

My end goal is calculating the homology of $S^2 \times S^2$, comparing it to that of $\mathbb C P^2 \ \# \ \mathbb C P^2$, and using the cup product to show homology is insufficient as a comparison.

I'm struggling with calculating the first of these. I managed to come up with a CW structure on the connected sum, but for the first space I was trying to use Mayer-Vietoris (unsuccessfully - I didn't find the right homology).

I'm wondering how to apply [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100170/cartesian-product-of-two-cw-complexes) on products of CW complexes - we use points $p$ and $q$, and abusing notation using the same letters for the space of that point. After a first attempt, I'm finding that we get all attachment maps the constant map to the point $(p,q)$ in the product, which would yield a decomposition (omitting the attachment map which is the same)
$$
(p,q) \cup (D^2 \times q) \cup (p \times D^2) \cup (D^2 \times D^2)
$$
which would be equal to $ S^2 \vee S^2 \vee S^4$ but that contradicts [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1767366/showing-that-s2-times-s2-and-s2-vee-s2-vee-s4-are-not-homotopy-equivale) which says this isn't even homotopy equivalent to $S^2 \times S^2$, let alone homeomorphic.

What is incorrect about my application of this, with which I'm hoping to apply it to other products?

Comment: You can (and should) use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in your title, as well as in the text of your post.

Comment: I've added that now - what are the recommendations on when not to use MathJax in the title? I feel like i remember seeing that - is that more for big integrals/things that wouldn't fit in a line?

Comment: Whoops forgot to tag @LeeMosher

Comment: It's not so much an issue of mathjax as it is of readability. Big integrals/things look terrible on the math.stackexchange front page. Formulas not written in mathjax look terrible on the math.stackexchange front page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is being precise about what $(p,q)\cup (\{p\}\times D^2\cup D^2\times \{q\}) \cup(D^2\times D^2)$ really is.

The second $\cup$ should refer to gluing a $D^4$ onto $S^2\vee S^2$ via an attaching map $S^3\to S^2\vee S^2$. Different such maps yield different spaces, the notation hides this fact.

The following illustrates how different attaching maps lead to different spaces:

1. One gets $S^2\vee S^2\vee S^4$ when picking the constant attaching map.
2. To arrive at $S^2\times S^2$ we use
   $$
   S^3 =\partial D^4 \cong \partial(D^2\times D^2) \cong S^1\times D^2 \cup_{S^1\times S^1}D^2\times S^1.
   $$
   The two maps $\pi \circ \text{pr}_2\colon S^1\times D^2 \to \{p\}\times S^2$ and $\pi \circ \text{pr}_1\colon D^2\times S^1 \to S^2\times \{q\}$ first projecting away from $S^1$, then collapsing the boundary of $D^2$ then yield our attaching map.

In the end you can use e.g. cellular homology to arrive at $H^*(S^2\times S^2)$.

Comment: Does the composition come from something natural? For instance attaching an $(n+m)$-cell $D^n \times D^m$, we have the $S^{n-1} \times D^m$ part mapped via the product of the attachment $\partial D^n = S^{n-1} \to X^{n-1}$ and then the natural "inclusion" where the $m$-cell was attached $D^m \to Y^m$ (for $Y^m$ the $m$-skeleton of $Y$, already constructed in our cellular realisation of some product $X \times Y$ when attaching $* \times D^m$ a smaller dimension cell)

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but $S^1\to *$ *is* the attaching map of the 2-cell in $S^2$, and the collapse $D^2\to S^2$ *is* the characteristic map of $D^2$ to the 2-skeleton of $S^2$.